# JSON api network call not returning reliable number of data each time I make the call (Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, networking

I am basically receiving news articles from newsapi.org. I have an array of sources (that user can select from) and then creating a for loop, where it iterates over the sources and makes the call to the server.

```
func fetchForYouArticles(sources: [NewsSource : Bool], completion: @escaping ([Articles]) -> ()) {
    var sourcesArray: [String] = []


    for source in sources.keys {
        sourcesArray.append(source.id)
    }

    //Fetched Sources Articles
    var fetchedArticles: [Articles] = []
    // Fetch articles from each source 

    for (index, s) in sourcesArray.enumerated() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=\(s)&apiKey=\(NetworkProperties.APIKEY)") else {
            fatalError()
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
          URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                 let sourcesList = try JSONDecoder().decode(ArticleList.self, from: data)

                fetchedArticles.append(contentsOf: sourcesList.articles)
                 print(sourcesList.articles)
                if index == (sourcesArray.count - 1) {
                     completion(fetchedArticles)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

        }.resume()

   }      
}
```

What happens here is that I am iterating through all the sources and then adding the sources in the URL and fetching the data. I then add all the fetched articles in a new array called `fetchedArticles`. Then I am checking if the index of the for loop equals to the total - 1, in which case I call the completion handler.

The problem is that I am not getting a reliable number of articles each time for same number of sources. Sometimes I will get 30 out of possible 40 articles. Other times I will get all 40. 
Sometimes the `print(sourcesList.articles)` line is called after this statement:

```
if index == (sourcesArray.count - 1) {
       completion(fetchedArticles)
 }
```

I am calling this function in viewWillAppear of my collectionViewController. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This is likely a result of `null` values returning from the API. Does your decodable class have optionals?

Comment: If the result of the last request is received before any of the previous requests has returned their results then you will call the completion handler to early. You should count and check the number of returned results rather than sent requests. In other words if you send request a, b and c but b takes extra long time so that you receive the results in the order a, c, b then the completion handler will be called with a and c while b will be ignored